# Is it possible to install Fedora 25 or newer without GUI from USB?

Tags: command-line, fedora, system-installation, live-usb

I have an nvidia 1070 graphics card and the Fedora GUI is painfully slow and mouse pointer is invisible. I've had similar problems installing Ubuntu, although it wasn't that slow I think. This makes it impossible to install with GUI. Is there a way to do everything with command line?

Comment: Well, this might help you https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Installation_Guide/ch-guimode-x86.html#ch-tuimode-x86 Its an old post, but probably is still working. Last but not least, its really weird that you are using a usb for your boot and you are having lag issues with your graphics..

Comment: Here is the latest documentation regarding the installation in text mode: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/sect-installation-text-mode.html

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this using the Live media, but you can with the netinstall image. [Use this link for the Fedora 25 Workstation Netinstall](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/25/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-25-1.3.iso), or find it in the right column under "Other Downloads" for [Workstation](https://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/25/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-netinst-x86_64-25-1.3.iso) or [Server](https://getfedora.org/en/server/download/). (If you are installing Fedora Atomic Host on bare metal, like for a compute farm, you can get the [Atomic Host ISO](https://getfedora.org/en/atomic/download/) in the same way.)

With this image, you can install in text mode by providing the `inst.text` option on the boot command line. You get to this from the initial install media boot screen:

[image: for f21 but it still applies]

Press `TAB` in BIOS mode or `e` in EFI mode to edit the command line, and add `inst.text` to the end. Then press `ENTER` (BIOS) or `Ctrl-X` (EFI) to boot.

Note that in text mode, you cannot use custom partitioning or advanced storage options, and you also must use a US keyboard. If you need something other than that, you might consider a fully-automated Kickstart install.

More on this in the [Fedora 25 Installation Guide](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/25/html/Installation_Guide/index.html).

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I don't understand why they don't have this mode as an option on the menu, next to the install with/without test options - it's not at all obvious that it exists.

Comment: I think the idea was to simplify the starting menu so it didn't have so many overwhelming choices.